# Access web.xml context-param in POJO with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How do I access a context-param inside a POJO using Spring? I thought perhaps by adding `@Component` it would be "managed" by Spring then I could use the `@Value` annotation. The String minutes = null rather than = 5 as set in the context.

```
@Component
 public class process {

       @Value("${minutes}")
       private static String minutes;
}
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>minutes</param-name>
    <param-value>5</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: You cannot use `@Value` on `static` fields.

Comment: Thanks, is there another way of accessing a configurable parameter?

Comment: Why does it have to be a `static` variable?

Answer (score 0):

**Check the given sample :**

`@Component
public class process {

   private String minutes;

   public String getMinutes(){
      minutes= context.getInitParameter(startTime);
      return minutes;
   }

@Autowired
ServletContext context;`

Comment: That code works when I put it into a Controller class, but in a static POJO it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: To load/initialize the attributes through Spring we compulsory not use the static object. If you want this value in you static object then you have to set set this value at the time of initialization of Application. Check my another answer for the same.

Answer (score 0):

At First you have to create one new "ServletContextListener"

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;

public class DataInitionlazationListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        try {
            ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
            Process.minutes = context.getInitParameter(startTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

POJO class with static variable :

```
public class Process {

   public static String minutes;

}
```

By using the above class it will initialize your POJO static variable: